# Running Test Modules in CANoe Using Python

Tags: python, testing, canoe

I developed a Python based CANOE Automation Code, wherein I launch CANOE, Open the Configuration and load the Test Specification and run it.

Now i want to wait till the Test Module execution is completed to note the Verdict. But not sure on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"""Execute XML Test Cases without a pass verdict"""
from time import sleep
import win32com.client as win32
import configparser
import time
from pandas.core.computation.expressions import set_test_mode
import pythoncom


testComplete = False

class TestModuleEvents(object):
    def OnReportGenerated(self,Success, SourceFullName, GeneratedFullName):
        print("Report Generated")
        testComplete = True
    def OnStop(self, value):
        print("Test Module Stopped")
        testComplete = True

    def OnStart(self):
        print("Test Module Started")
        testComplete = True

class TestConfigurationEvents(object):
    def OnStart(self):
        print("Measurement Started")
        testComplete = False

    def OnStop(self):
        print("Measurement Stopped")
        testComplete = True

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('usecase02_configuration.properties')
configurationPath = config.get('TESTCONFIGURATION', 'configurationpath')
testspec = config.get('TESTCONFIGURATION', 'testspecification')

CANoe = win32.DispatchEx("CANoe.Application")
CANoe.Open(configurationPath)

testSetup = CANoe.Configuration.TestSetup
testSetup.TestEnvironments.Add(testspec)
test_env = testSetup.TestEnvironments.Item('Test Environment')
test_env = win32.CastTo(test_env, "ITestEnvironment2")


print(report.FullName)

# Get the XML TestModule (type <TSTestModule>) in the test setup
test_module = test_env.TestModules.Item('Tester')
CANoe.Measurement.Start()
sleep(5)   # Sleep because measurement start is not instantaneous

win32.WithEvents(test_module, TestModuleEvents)
test_module.Start()

# sleep(60)

while test_module.Verdict==0:
    time.sleep(1)

# test_module.Stop()
print(test_module.Verdict)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You already have the code for starting the testmodule as well as the code for waiting until the testmodule is finished. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the code. If you look at the while loop

`while test_module.Verdict==0:
    time.sleep(1)`

I assumed that verdict by default would be 0 and on pass or fail would become 1 or 2. But it didnt wait in the while look as the Verdict was 1 by default.

Then i tried to change the while as shown below

`while not testComplete:
    time.sleep(1)`

Hoping that when the testmodule run is completed, it would invoke onStop inside TestModuleEvents and set the testCompleted=true. But that also didnt happen.

Need support in invoking onStop and terminate while.

Answer (score 2):

You have all pieces in place. I think the only problem is a misunderstanding of the way global variables work in python.

You declare `testComplete` in the global scope of your python file. Inside of `TestModuleEvents.OnStop` you declare another variable named `testComplete`. This instance is completely unrelated to the variable in the global scope.

Change your `OnStop`-handler (and the others as well) to something like this:

```
    def OnStop(self, value):
        global testComplete
        print("Test Module Stopped")
        testComplete = True
```

This will *import* the global variable into your scope and set that one to `True` instead of creating a new one.

After doing that, change your while loop to:

```
while not testComplete:
    time.sleep(1)
```